# Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: GET request of: org/b eanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central failed

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to build my Maven project but it is failing to GET org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central repo http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Below is the error trace when I used mvn archetype:generate from command line:

```
C:\Users\SO310400\workspace\analytics>mvn -U -e archetype:generate
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadat
a.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-m
etadata.xml (13 KB at 11.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata
.xml (20 KB at 15.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-a
rchetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (730 B at 1.1 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Credit Dashboard Analytics 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ analytics >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ analytics <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ analytics ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0
b4.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:05.313s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 07 13:10:12 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.3:generate (default-cli) on project analytics: Execution default-cli of goal or
g.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate failed: Plugin org.ap
ache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could n
ot be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4 from/to
central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/beanshell/bsh
/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central failed: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) on pro
ject analytics: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-arc
hetype-plugin:2.3:generate failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archety
pe-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transf
er artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apach
e.org/maven2): GET request of: org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from centra
l failed
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-c
li of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate failed:
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3 or one of its depende
ncies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2
.0b4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/
beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.
maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be
 resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4 from/to centr
al (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b
4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.re
solve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPlug
inRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPlugi
nRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(Defa
ultBuildPluginManager.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:83)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
transfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4 from/to central (http://repo.maven
.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from
central failed
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
acts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepen
dencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.re
solve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:200)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tran
sfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apa
che.org/maven2): GET request of: org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from cent
ral failed
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(Wa
gonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(Wa
gonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.r
un(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Runn
ableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: GET request of: org/b
eanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:3
49)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:3
10)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:2
87)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.r
un(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:660)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSess
ionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:204)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.ContentLengt
hInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.EofSensorInputS
tream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:493)

        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:3
39)
        ... 9 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
C:\Users\SO310400\workspace\analytics>
```

Since I am using a proxy environment from within my workplace network I have the proxy settings in my C:/Users/MYNAME/.m2/settings.xml (where M2_REPO=C:/Users/MYNAME/.m2/repository) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>MYNAME</username>
      <password>MYPASSWORD</password>
      <host>MYPROXYSERVER</host>
      <port>MYPROXYPORT</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>google.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>


</settings>
```

But I am getting the following error in my project POM (C:/Users/MYNAME/workspace/analytics/pom.xml)

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'snapshotRepository'. One of '{"http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repository}' is expected.


Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-c
li of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate failed:
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3 or one of its depende
ncies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2
.0b4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/
beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar from central failed
```

Comment: This line `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'snapshotRepository'. One of '{"http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repository}' is expected.` is very interesting...you should fix this first....

Comment: The download of the jar from the link http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar is failing due to network error. I am accessing from proxy domain and may be the access to the jar is blocked due to harmful downloads https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?p=ui_download_errors&rd=1

Comment: But the point is that the infrastructure is your problem and not Maven. Furthermore i would recommend to start using a repository manager.